# Difference between alias and withColumnRenamed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

What is the difference between:

```
my_df = my_df.select(col('age').alias('age2'))
```

and

```
my_df = my_df.select(col('age').withColumnRenamed('age', 'age2'))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second expression is not going to work, you need to call `withColumnRenamed()` on your `dataframe`.
I assume you mean:

```
my_df = my_df.withColumnRenamed('age', 'age2')
```

And to answer your question, there is no difference.

Comment: yes! sorry I got confused :) thank you!

Comment: yes of course! Here you go :)